# Could we please have tag description on hover when posting/editing?

Tags: feature-request, edits, design

Having the tag's description on hover is really useful to check you don't misuse it.

Unfortunately, this description isn't displayed on hover when you're editing a question and I don't see any simple way to get to that description other than editing the tag and recreating it, which isn't convenient.

Could we please have the tag description on hover so that we can more efficiently fix them ?

The goal is to be able, when editing a question, to have a look at the correctness of the tag choice, something which usually comes last as we fix from top to bottom.

Comment: This might help with a problem I've noticed. The tag "double" gets questions that use the word double but have nothing to do with the tag: [Perl - double dollar sign: what function does it perform?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27749136/1798593)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I would blame the fact that the double tag exist at all.

Comment: Oh man I want this so much you don't even know. So many times I go in and am, shall we say, highly dubious of the post's tags, but it's tedious to backspace each one to be sure it's really reasonable. And yet, each tag has that X button to remove it efficiently in editing!

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Display Tag Excerpt tooltips when editing a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/display-tag-excerpt-tooltips-when-editing-a-question).

Comment: As a work around, you can see the description if your cursor is "on" the tag.  You can do this by moving the cursor to the tag or clicking on the tag when in the editor.

Comment: Just click the tag. Much less annoying than hover.

Comment: @minitech I don't see how hovering is annoying.  Plus why should there be a different interface when editing?  If I'm not editing a question I hover if I want to see the description.  If I click the tag when not editing I'm taken to the tags page.  I think the question that should be answered by those defending the current implementation is "why should it be this way instead of being consistent"?

Comment: I agree with Dason but thanks @minitech : I hadn't seen that solution which is a usable workaround

Comment: @Dason: Clicking a tag when editing should edit the tag because you’re editing, which isn’t a reasonable behaviour when you’re not editing. So I suppose that answers the question of why there should be a different interface when editing. Hovering is annoying because you have to wait a little while for the box to pop up (and this itself is an improvement over not waiting!), only to disappear when you accidentally move a little too far off when copying something, for example.

Comment: Happy Badge to you!

Answer (score 2):

The tag description shows in the suggestions box when you're typing in the tag:

[image: Tag description shows when typing tags in]

I think this mostly alleviates the problem of when you want to proactively check the tag, but it does have one drawback: you can't see it once the tag is added. In spite of the fact that this is a bit wonky, adding hover only adds very little to this, since you can currently just backspace a letter to get the suggestions back. **Your proposal is still only helpful when an asker or editor who is being proactive with the tags.**

If your goal is better tag usage for everyone, I think that the feature request needs to be more passive, by which I mean the site should do something that draws users' attention to tag descriptions to encourage them to consider it instead of hiding that information until sought. Maybe something more like a list that shows the tags and their descriptions all the time above an "Add Tag" bar:

[image: Tag and description above add tag bar]

Comment: "...you can't see it once the tag is added."  Not entirely true.  If you click on the tag will will go into a text edit mode where you can see the suggestions and descriptions.  You can "cancel" your editing by clicking at the end of the box or outside it.

Comment: @JasonMArcher This is more or less what I meant when I said, "since you can currently just backspace a letter to get the suggestions back." I'll reword later to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I thought that was related to "re-adding" the tag mentioned before.