# How are the feature requests prioritized?

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

I wanted to propose a new feature but I searched for it first and I found this one (which is what I was looking for): [Could we please have tag description on hover when posting/editing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281858/could-we-please-have-tag-description-on-hover-when-posting-editing)

I upvoted it, but it already has 100+ upvotes, so I was wondering why it was not implemented.

I suppose it's a matter of priorities, but I don't understand why other questions ([Add syntax highlight 'default' for tag [elm] (currently 'none')](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341319/add-syntax-highlight-default-for-tag-elm-currently-none)) with less than 5 upvotes and added much later got implemented sooner than one added years ago and with a significant amount of upvotes.

How are feature requests prioritized?

Comment: Developer time plays a significant part in your 2 examples.  A few seconds of effort for the syntax highlighting is a lot different than a feature that will require hundreds of developer hours of work.  But even then, feature requests are not a popularity contest.  Stack Overflow, Inc makes the decisons on what and how to implement, and when.  The community feedback via meta is only a small part of that.  I'm certain there is a duplicate arund here somewhere, but can't find it at the moment

Comment: There's a goldmine of information in [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange?rq=1) and the related questions that are linked in that question.

Comment: Typically they will look at any feature request with a high enough score. Sometimes they can fall through the cracks though, until prodded: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273003/can-we-have-a-tool-tip-with-the-full-title-for-links-to-hot-meta-posts-that-don

Comment: All feature requests take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100)....

Comment: @TylerH - Let's hope they will at least *look* at **any** request

Comment: related answer about how (ir)relevant voting is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360053/should-a-feature-request-be-voted-based-on-its-priority/360063#360063

Comment: If it's got a tag of [bug] or [feature-requests] then at least one dev has seen it.

Comment: @rene "All feature requests take 6 to 8 weeks" ??? what are you talking about, some takes a few days to be solved, other take years. Or is it more like "if after 2 years it haven't been done, you can't expect it anymore, they won't do it"

Comment: @AntoinePelletier you either didn't click the link or didn't get the story there ...

Comment: @rene Ho I see, sorry... Well, would it be something reasonable to publish the list of current task being done ? And the list of next tasks that are about to be taken by dev ? This way people would see where are SO priorities ?

Comment: It is rather going too slow and they have plenty of things to do for non-public features like Jobs/Trends/Enterprise/Channels/Documentation/Teams/New-nav/Technical debt/Area51/Chat. Don't have the illusion we prioritize anything here or that it matters that a feature is put somewhere on a list on meta. Closest you'll get is [TeamDAG update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301449) and [What features did the Community Team discuss, have implemented, or have denied last month?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291031). SE is open as much as they can but they're not *managed* by us.

Comment: @rene TeamDAG's Update is kind of satisfying. Thanks